# How do I use a Simple Feature Collection (sfc) from the sf package with the elevatr package to load elevation data?

Tags: r, elevation, sf

I'm trying to [load elevation data from AWS using the `elevatr` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elevatr/vignettes/introduction_to_elevatr.html), with a region defined as a Simple Features Collection from the `sf` package. Here's a simple example:

```
library(elevatr)
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)

counties <- us_counties(map_date = "1930-01-01", resolution = "high", states = c("NY"))
elevation <- get_elev_raster(counties$geometry, z = 9, src = "aws")
```

This gives an error:

```
Error in if (attributes(class(locations)) %in% c("raster", "sp")) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (class(locations) == "data.frame") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (class(locations) == "SpatialPoints") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (class(locations) == "SpatialPointsDataFrame") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Presumably because the sfc is a collection of polygons and `MULTIPOINT` objects, which aren't supported by the `get_elev_raster` function of the `elevatr` package.

**Is there any way to use these packages together? With the end result being an sfc object that also has various forms of elevation data for each point?**

---

<sub>I'm getting the data this way because it doesn't seem like the `st_read` function from the `sf` package can read ESRI ASCII files.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counties <- us_counties(map_date = "1930-01-01", resolution = "high", states = c("NY"))
```

this has created an `sf` object, but:

```
elevation <- get_elev_raster(counties$geometry, z = 9, src = "aws")
```

this expects an `sp` object. Convert `sf` to `sp` with:

```
counties_sp = as(counties, "Spatial")
```

then this should work:

```
elevation = get_elev_raster(counties_sp, z=..... etc.....)
```

I cant replicate your code at the moment because the USABoundariesData package is refusing to install...

Comment: Thank you, that works. Now I need to read up on how to get RasterLayer objects to play nicely with `sf` objects.

Comment: (And I don't know why the `USABoundariesData` package won't install for you. This command usually works for me: `install.packages("USAboundariesData", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source", dependencies=TRUE)` but that's just pulled from the installation of `USABoundaries`)